# запятая перед "что"

Tags: пунктуация

Ложка (мы все знаем, что это и можем понимать другого).

После "что это" нужна запятая? Мы знаем и можем, вроде бы, не нужна. Но смысл, как будто бы, теряется.

Answer (score 1):

Я не совсем понимаю смысл конструкции в скобках. Каким образом знание того, что такое ложка, помогает понять другого?
Ваши рассуждения про "знаем и можем" тоже не совсем доходят. Тут же не просто однородные сказуемые, есть еще и "что это", которое и предопределяет необходимость обособления.

Но в любом случае, запятая совершенно необходима. 
Вы же перед "что" её поставили, как можно регулярно ставить открывающую - и при этом забывать про закрывающую?
***Ложка (мы все знаем, что это, и можем понимать другого)***

"Что это" - подчиненное предложение, относится только к "знаем", значит его надо обособить запятыми. **С двух сторон!**

Comment: Спасибо вам!!!))) это книга по семантике, поэтому знание того, что такое ложка, помогает понять другого, что он имеет в виду, когда говорит "ложка")) не поняла про "не совсем доходят", можете по другому сформулировать? Спасибо, вот не доходит до меня, где подчиненное предложение, а где обстоятельство или уточнение))